# How to make an invites command, which updates based on whether the members are still in the server

Tags: discord.js

How would I go about creating an invites command (a command that shows a member's invites) that will update when a member that they invited leaves

i.e a person has invited 5 people, and their invite count is 5. One of the people they invited leaves, and their invite count goes down to 4

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bot itself cannot send an invite to a user, so one of the users involved need to send the invite anyway.

One way of achieving your goal is to add a 'identified' role and lock all channels for anyone without it. then make the server public and create a 'welcome' channel for people without the 'identified' role.
members will be identified using the 'invite' command which will be available only in the locked channels.

Note: all invites to the server should be disabled except for invites to the 'welcome' channel.

Then, Create a .json file (or database) for storing members' scores. and in the invite command, update the information stored there.

In the database create two dictionaries:

- In the first: for each user store the id of the user who invited him.
- In the second: for each user store the number of current members in the server that were invited by that user

updating these two dictionaries is easy:

- When inviting user: set their value in the first dictionary to be the id of the user who invited them. also add 1 to the inviter's score in the second dictionary.
- On member leave, find the person who invited them, and decrease their score in the second dictionary by 1.